# Github cache restored on exact key, but cache-hit is false

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a cache for `swift-format` build that is being restored via an exact key, but the `cache-hit` output variable is being set to `false`. Is this a bug and if not, how do I fix it?

```
  build-caches-ubuntu:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.3.0

      - name: Create swift-format build cache
        id: cache-swift-format
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: .build
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-spm-${{ hashFiles('**/Package.resolved') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-spm-

      - name: Output cache-hit
        run: |
          echo "cache-hit: '${{ steps.cache-swift-format.outputs.cache-hit }}'"

      - name: build swift-format
        if: steps.cache-swift-format.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          ls .build
          git clone https://github.com/apple/swift-format.git
          cd swift-format
          swift build --disable-sandbox -c release
          mv .build ..
```

The result is:

```
Run actions/cache@v3
Received 81635546 of 81635546 (100.0%), 111.7 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~78 MB (81635546 B)
/usr/bin/tar -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/ac6de258-20a8-45aa-859f-a76eea492e34/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/andreiz/my-repo --use-compress-program unzstd
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-spm-46aa9e2c01612335b78177ce757beabbd0a44505706a81e32520e0748260f05e

Run echo "cache-hit: 'false'"
  echo "cache-hit: 'false'"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
cache-hit: 'false'

Run ls .build
artifacts
checkouts
plugins
release
release.yaml
repositories
workspace-state.json
```

So the cache is definitely being restored, but `cache-hit` is set to `false`.

Comment: Are you sure it's an exact hit? If you expand the arguments to the action, is the restored cache the same as the full key parameter, rather than the partial?

Comment: You're right, the actions show a different key.

Run actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: .build
    key: Linux-spm-bab10986b9f7114edd6de7902fa74701308c3c681fcc1b7b7af0272a88b9bc47

How come it says 'restored cache successfully' and then lists the exact (wrong) key?

Comment: Because it _did_ successfully restore a cache, and that _is_ the key of the cache it restored. It's not "wrong", it's a match based on the rules you supplied.